# cycles in a group of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $S_A$ be the group of permutations of a set $A$ (finite or infinite). We say that a permutation $\sigma\in S_A$ is a  finite cycle iff $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ where $a_i\in A$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. $i,e$ $\sigma(a_i)=a_{i+1}$ for $i<n$, $\sigma(a_n)=a_1$ and $\sigma(b)=b$ for each $b\in A\setminus\{a_1,\dots, a_n\}$.

I prove the following statement: Let $r,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sigma\in S_A$ a finite cycle with length $n$. If $n$ is odd and $r=2^k$ for some $k>0$ then $\sigma^r$ is a cycle.

My question: The previous statement is a "if, and only if" statement?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Thanks, I fixed.

Comment: You'd better look at that "proof" as the result you claim is false. $6\not| 9$, $9$ is odd, and $(123456789)^6$ is a product of three $3$-cycles.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think that in this form the statement is true. Thanks for your observation.

Comment: Sure that's true. But weak. If $\sigma$ is a cycle of order $n$ then so is every $\sigma^r$ with $r$ coprime with $n$. If $r$ is not coprime with $n$ then $\sigma^r$ splits into a proper product of cycles.

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks a lot!!